# How to make Python differentiate between upper and lower characters.

Tags: python

Hello guys I hope you will help me with a small problem that I did not figured out yet.
Here is the description of the homework to have an idea first about what I am working on.

*" In this part of the homework, you will write a program that inputs two different
characters in the form of "c1-c2", where c1
is the first character and c2
is the second
character. You need to check the validity of this input. That is, the input should
start with a letter, followed by a dash (-), and it should end with another letter case
insensitively (it means that "a" and "A" are the same characters). Please note that
the characters to be obtained from the user must be different from each other. In
case that the user enters an invalid input, your program should continuously
prompt for the required value until (s)he enters a valid one."*

Here is some sample runs:

- Please enter two different characters in the form c1-c2: a-A
- Invalid input!
- Please enter two different characters in the form c1-c2: a-B
  (The program should stop if it is correct.)

Here is what I tried so far:

```
ascii_letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

def process(Z):
    if Z[0] in ascii_letters:
        return True
    if Z[1] == '-':
        return True
    if Z[2] in ascii_letters:
        return True
    if Z[0] != Z[2]:
        return True
    if Z[0] != Z[2].upper():
        return True
    if Z[0] != Z[2].lower():
        return True 

X = False
while X == False:
    ask = input("Please enter two different characters in the form c1-c2: ")
    if process(ask) == False :
        print("Invalid input!")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: A function *ends* when it hits a `return`.

Comment: Where is the `return False` statement?

Comment: @user2357112 what do you suggest ?

Comment: @TomWojcik I tried to put it after like "else: return false" but it did not work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: You haven't shown your test cases, actual output, and desired output.  Your posted code exits as soon as you find *one* character of correct input, rather than checking for all being correct.  Draw a flowchart of your code, and note how it works.  Compare it ot a flowchart of your *desired* result.  You can't just exit after one check.

Comment: @Prune please can you tell what do I need to change ? should I use elif statement? how do I combine all the lines together ?

Comment: This is not a homework service.  There are plenty of examples on line for writing compound logical checks.  How did none of those answer your questions?  If you are truly lost on how to fix your code after the comments posted, this usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Prune forget about the fact that it is a homework it is also a code as all the codes in this site and I am having a problem with and stuck thats why I am asking for help. Its totally my right to ask for help from people who know more than me. what r u talkin about?

Comment: Again, read the guidelines.  You've essentially asked us to write the code for you.  No attempt to apply the problems we pointed out.  However, since others have handed you several finished solutions, it appears to be a moot point.

Comment: @Prune I did not ask people to write my code for me, I asked them to help me find the problem in my code. And I published what I tried so far.

Comment: @Prune Did you read my post at least ? :)

Comment: @Prune - he posted a clear statement of the problem and his attempt at a solution.  I was able to copy the program and run it. This question is very well written. "this is not a homework service" but it is a place where people can get help on problems they legitimately tried to solve.

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you. Next time I wont use the word "homework" to avoid any kind of problems.

Comment: Please do NOT change the post title to "Post closed ...".  Your post isn't just for you!  It's for others to benefit as well.  That's the main idea behind this site: not to answer one question for one person, but to answer questions for others to learn from as well.

Comment: @Prune's objection isn't the use of the word "homework".  It's that you didn't do your due diligence to solve the issue.  Please read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).  Much of that is above your level, but bookmark it!  Put print statements in your code to see what it's doing and why, and learn from it.  You'll get a lot more benefit from this site, and do better in your programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inbuilt function **-isalpha()** will be helpful for your homework.

```
while True:
    ask=input('Please enter two different characters in the form c1-c2: ')
    if len(ask)!=3:
        continue
    if ask[1] == '-' and ask[0].isalpha() and ask[2].isalpha() and ask[0]!=ask[2]:
        break
```

The **isalpha()** function returns **True** if the given string has all alphabets.

Comment: This is what I already posted except it leaves out the checks for character length and a case-insensitive compare. We are going backwards here!

Answer (score 1):

Here your process almost always terminate at the first check:

```
def process(Z):
    if Z[0] in ascii_letters:
        return True
```

You need to nest your condition, and 'return' only when all the conditions are filled, a fast example:

```
def process(Z):
    if Z[0] in ascii_letters:
        if Z[1] == '-':
           if Z[2] in ascii_letters:
              return True
    return False
```

Note you will want to check for that Z is the right size before accessing Z[2]. And you need as well to add the check about same-letter. So a solution for your problem would be:

```
def process(Z):
    if len(Z) == 3
       and Z[0] in ascii_letters
       and Z[1] == '-'
       and Z[2] in ascii_letters
       and Z[0].upper() != Z[2].upper():
              return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thank you Luc , I'll give it a try and see.

Answer (score 1):

Strings have methods you can use to validate the input. Use them! You can split on '-' and verify you have 2 characters of length 1, check whether they are alphabetic and compare the upper case version of each.

```
def process(Z):
    parts = Z.split("-")
    return (len(parts)==2 and len(parts[0])==1 and len(parts[1])==1 
        and parts[0].isalpha() 
        and parts[0].upper() == parts[1].upper())
```

`isalpha` works for all unicode characters so you don't have to worry whether the user entered text in some strange language.

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle this is with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#module-re). Their is a regex library as part of the standard python library.

```
import re
u_input = 'your string'

def validate(input):
    # chars must be different
    if input[0] == input[-1:]:
        return False
    # begin and end with upper or lower a-z with dash in middle
    pattern = '[a-zA-Z]{1}-[a-zA-Z]{1}'
    result = re.match(pattern, input)
    # re.match returns None if no match
    if not result:
        return False:
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I cannot use these functions because I am still a beginner and I dont know how to use them in the next parts of my homework.

Comment: @DirtyLilBirdy Much of programming is learning to stretch outside your comfort zone. Many times, the simplest solution requires you to do a little bit of outside learning or research. Using solutions like this instead of 10 if else statements will be what separates you from a run of the mill programmer. Unless there are explicit instructions to the contrary, I would highly suggest doing a little reading on Regular Expressions, and teaching your class the benefits of them.

Comment: You're definitely right ! I'll take your advice as consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it as similar to your code as possible and it's quite simple to understand. I think I considered all required conditions. If not, tell me.

```
from string import ascii_letters

def validity_check(input_chars):
    try:
        # if cant be splitted raises Exception which results in restart
        char_1, char_2 = input_chars.split("-")

        # if characters not in alphabet restarts
        chars_in_alphabet = char_1 in ascii_letters and char_2 in ascii_letters
        if not chars_in_alphabet:
            return False

        # if characters are the same letter restarts
        same_latter = char_1.lower() == char_2.lower()
        if same_latter:
            return False

        # I'm not sure if you want to check if the first letter
        # is small and the second one is capital
        # if so add this block
        # chars_letter_size = char_1 in ascii_letters.lower() and char_2 in ascii_letters.upper()
        # if not chars_letter_size:
        #     return False

        return True

    except:
        return False


while True:
    ask = input("Please enter two different characters in the form c1-c2: ")
    if validity_check(ask):
        break
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works perfectly, I appreciate your help :D